# Adding a Item to Listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Im trying to simply add a Item to a Listview and display it. But if I add it it just shows me the path of that string istead of the tring itself. I'm sure it's a simple mistake but I cant find it.

```
public class zutatenHinzufuegen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> zutatenliste;
    private ListView zutatenView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> zutatenadapter;
    private TextInputLayout zutatInput;
    private TextInputLayout anzahlInput;
    private int anzahlint;
    private String einheitInput;
    private Button hinzufuegen_button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zutaten_hinzufuegen_linear);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.menu_zutaten);

        // Spinner
        final Spinner einheiten_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_einheiten2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> einheiten_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(zutatenHinzufuegen.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.einheiten));
        einheiten_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        einheiten_spinner.setAdapter(einheiten_adapter);

        // List
        zutatInput =(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputZutat2);
        einheitInput =(String) einheiten_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        anzahlInput = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputAnzahl2);
        try {
            anzahlint = Integer.parseInt(anzahlInput.toString());
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){}

        hinzufuegen_button = findViewById(R.id.zutat_hinzufuegen_button2);
        zutatenView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.zutatenliste2);
        zutatenliste= new ArrayList<>();
        zutatenadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.zutatenliste_items,R.id.textitemliste,zutatenliste);
        // zutatenadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, zutatenliste);
        zutatenView.setAdapter(zutatenadapter);


        hinzufuegen_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // hinzufuegen(v , einheiten_spinner);
                ZutatClass newzutat = new ZutatClass(zutatInput.toString(),anzahlint,einheitInput);

                zutatenliste.add((String) newzutat.zutat_sting);
                zutatenadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
        });
    }

}
```

[image: This is what it shows me when i press the button a few times]

This is what I see when i press the button a few times

I'm new to Android Studio and java so I hope it's not to much of a mess.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add Edittext inside the TextInputLayout and then get a text like this `ZutatClass newzutat = new ZutatClass(zutatInput.getEditText().getText().toString(),anzahlint,einheitInput);` on your on click method

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is that you are trying to convert a TextInputLayout to string instead of getting the text from it and convert it to string , try the code below

```
hinzufuegen_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // hinzufuegen(v , einheiten_spinner);
                ZutatClass newzutat = new ZutatClass(zutatInput.getEditText().getText().toString(),anzahlintgetEditText().g etText().toString()
,einheitInput);

                zutatenliste.add((String) newzutat.zutat_sting);
                zutatenadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
        });
```

`zutatInput.toString() --> zutatInput.getEditText().getText()`

`anzahlint.toString() --> anzahlint.getEditText().getText().toString()`